# Paging data from a web service

Tags: paging

I'm working on a module that uses soap to fetch data from a webservices.
Data are ok, and I'll use theme functions to display them as a list.
I should also to split results in pages, like views.
Is there a way to add a pager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```
 foreach ($result as $node) 
{
    $rows[] = array('data' => array("".  $node  ."...
```

"));
    $html = theme('table',array('header' => $header,'rows'=>$rows,'caption' => '','sticky' => FALSE,'empty' => 'No details found...','attributes'=>array('class'=>'table-class'),));
    $html.= theme('pager',array('tags' => array(),'quantity'=> 10));
}

Comment: I try it, but the pager is not created, I've only html from the table

Comment: Ok, I've to initialize the pager and it works.